# WSO2 Developer Studio cannot open Proxy wizard

Tags: eclipse, proxy, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I installed the WSO2 Developer Studio 3.2.0 in a Eclipse Juno (Build id: 20120614-1722).

Using the graphical wizard, I've done the following steps:

- created a `Carbon Application Project`
- created a `ESB config Project` inside the project.
- selected the `endpoints` folder and created an address `Endpoint`.

When I select the `proxy-services` folder, right click and choose `New -> Proxy Service`, nothing happens, nothing appears.

But, if I delete the endpoint created and try to create a proxy, the wizard appears normally and the proxy is created.

I already try to delete the `.metadata` folder, restart the eclipse, close and reopen the project, and nothing works.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which Java version are you using? WSO2 Developer Studio 3.2.0 is compatible with jdk 1.7.0.

I tried your scenario with jdk 1.6.0 and was able to recreate the issue. Then I changed the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to point to jdk1.7.0_25 home and bin, and things seem to work fine.

Please try it out and check if it fixes your problem as well.

Regards,
Anuradha

Comment: Works with JDK 1.6.0 on Windows 7 for me.

Comment: Running eclipse with `-vm /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java` argument make it works. Thanks.

Comment: Now, the problem is the graphical tool for edit the flow of the proxy don't allow to add endpoints. When I add and try to save, the endpoint disapears, but sequences don't. Weird..